# How Can I Minimize A Borderless Form Completely?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, windowstate

In my application I have my Main Form and other borderless forms that sit on top.  When I minimize the main form, I want to minimize all forms, but ONLY show the main form in the taskbar.  Currently what is happening is that the Main Form goes into the task bar, but all the other open forms create mini rectangles in the bottom left corner just above the taskbar.

Is there a way I can hide these ugly rectangles?  Clicking on each rectangle will bring up that particular window (which I wish to prevent).  I only want to give the user the option of clicking the main form in the taskbar to bring up all windows automatically.

Thanks

**Edit**

To hide all forms, I have added the following code to my `Resize` event in the Main Form:

```
Private Sub frmDashBoard_Resize(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Resize
        If Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized Then
            If focusedForm IsNot Nothing Then
                If focusedForm.Tag Is "StorePage" Then
                    focusedForm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized
                End If
            End If
        End If

        If Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized Then
            If focusedForm IsNot Nothing Then
                If focusedForm.Tag Is "StorePage" Then
                    focusedForm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
                End If
            End If
        End If
End Sub
```

Basically, I set my StorePage to `focusedForm` when it is open.  So `focusedForm` will reference the topmost form within my application.

Comment: What did you entered for the [ShowInTaskBar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.showintaskbar(v=vs.110).aspx) Property of your Borderless Forms?

Comment: hide the minimized windows (aka ugly rectangles) with `ShowInTaskBar = True`

Comment: I have the `ShowInTaskBar` property set to False.  If I set it to True, then I get an entry in the taskbar for that individual window which I don't want.  I only want a single taskbar entry for the Main Form...if possible.

Comment: Can you please post the code you use to hide the forms

Comment: It Looks like you want to devlop some Kind of Dashboard, did you though about creating a MDI Application

Comment: Yes I did venture down that path, but I had to scrap my code and revert to SDI.  I had a requirement to continuously move forms to the front and have them maximised but MDI couldn't support that nicely.  I ran into a lot of trouble so I decided to revert.  But turns out I'm having just as many issues with focusing now with SDI.  I can't win.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't minimize your forms, make them invisible instead, which if you don't want to see them, nor have them show in the taskbar, is really what you want:

```
If focusedForm.Tag Is "StorePage" Then
    focusedForm.Visible = (Me.WindowState <> FormWindowState.Minimized)
End If
```

etc.

Comment: HeyHeyJC - works great on Minimize, but when I restore, for some reason it is adding an entry to the Taskbar for the borderless forms....strange

Comment: Hmm. I'm not seeing that here. Is ShowInTaskBar still False?

Comment: Yes it is, but I have just re-added it into the `WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximed` code and it seems to have fixed it.  Looks like it's resetting that property when the form is restored (well in my application anyway).

Comment: Cool. Could you maybe mark my answer? Hate to ask, but I lost my previous login, and I'm completely handicapped with no rep.

Comment: Yeah absolutely...thanks for your help!  I would've marked it anyway, so no stress about asking.

Comment: Thanks. Keep the questions coming :)